# Can I take the SessionID returned from the SOAP API and use it in a URL Access call to SSRS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Two things; first is I keep getting a 401 exception on the last line.  I had thought that re-using the session would allow me to not only NOT have to resend the credentials but would also let me access the report by URL.  It does neither...

Second, what do I do with the `response` once I have it to display it in the browser for the User?

This is what I have so far but I am unsure where to go with this from here....

```
 var rs = new ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionService();
        rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserID", "Pswd", "myDomain");

        var execInfo = rs.LoadReport("/Nav Reports/OpenSalesOrderByCustomer", null);
        var format = "HTML4";

        string requestUri = string.Format(
      @"https://reports.myServer.com/ReportServer/?{0}&rs:SessionId={1}&rs:Format={2}",
      execInfo.ReportPath,
      execInfo.ExecutionID,
      format
      );
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserID", "Pswd", "myDomain");
        var response = request.GetResponse();
```

For Background info -->
I am trying to setup Remote Report processing with SSRS on my asp.net web forms app.  I would simply use the Report Viewer control but it's hideous looking and not acceptable to our user base.  The URL Access returns a much better looking and formatted report and is acceptable but I have to pass Security Credentials.  I would use SOAP API except it returns a non-styled html 'blob' and also removes the Toolbar functionality that we want to use.

So, I seem to be left with figuring out a way to use the SOAP API to authenticate a session and then somehow use that to use URL Access.

Answer (score -1):

Just call the SOAP API, get the bytes, and return those bytes to the user with appropriate headers, content-type: application/pdf, content-disposition:attachment;filename=report.pdf.  You don't need to do multiple calls to the report server.

Comment: Thanks for responding and I appreciate it.  However I can't really do what you suggest as I (A) was trying to return it as HTML and (B) I was hoping to have access to the toolbar for Exporting and Printing.

Comment: Build your own toolbar and change the type you request from the server

Comment: Are you saying that it's not possible to do what I'm asking or that you believe it's simpler to rebuild it from scratch?

Comment: I am halfway to building my tool bar ..The problem I am facing is when I export to excel and PDF the report renders again ..How to overcome the delay of running report all over ?  I was able to to paging by splitting html report ..